# Rails complicated scope with has_many association query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to implement an approval screen which has two model
Building( the building to be approved ) and Approver.

The building class looks like this

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :approval, as: :approvable
end
```

Approver class looks like this

```
class Approver < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :approvable, polymorphic: true
  scope :rejected, -> { where(approval_status:2) }
  scope :returned, -> { where(approval_status:3) }
  scope :finally_approved, -> { where(approval_status:1).where(user_id: 1) }
end

#pending = 0 , approved = 1, rejected = 2 , returned = 3
#admin user_id = 1 for final approving
```

Basical the approving is done bottom to top, meaning the staff needs to approve it  first then finally the admin approves it.

The rule is simple if a staff reject/return it, it will be automatically marked as returned/rejected and it will not need the admin approval

What I need is to get the Buildings that are pending, finally approved(done) , rejected(i have already done this) and returned(done)

I can get the approved buildings by running this line

```
 BuildingApproval.joins(:approval).merge(Approval.finally_approved)
```

this works because the admin can only approve it once his colleagues approve it and buildings that are rejected/returned by colleagues are not shown to the admin.

Getting the rejected and returned is pretty easy because I just need to find if one of the approvals are rejected/returned regardless whether the admin/staff does it .

```
BuildingApproval.joins(:approval).merge(Approval.rejected)
```

The only problem is when getting the pending I need to check if the admins approval is pending and the staffs didn't reject/return it. Any help will be appreciated!